# IIS deployment error file is locked by an external process

Tags: iis, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, file-in-use

I am facing file_is_use error while deploying .netcore api from azure pipeline to on-prem IIS server by using the tasks following task  in CD pipeline

[image]

Steps I have tried but still error persists :

1. Stop the application , deploy and than start

[image]

2. Enable App offline in Web Deploy task

[image]

But still facing the File_in_use issue

[image]

Comment: You can use  [Resource Monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/643312#643312) to check which process using this `<your_app_name>.dll` file.

Comment: And you also could try add `<GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>true</GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>` in your .`csproj` file, and check it works or not.

Comment: tried this but still same error

Comment: Have you check the process by using Resource Monitor ? What can we found ?

Comment: yes dll file is locked by same API .

Comment: When I kill the process manually and redeploy it works

Comment: Do you mind me summarize the comment as answer ^-^ It will help more forum users know how to fix this kind of issue by using `Resource Monitor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When IIS encounters a file locked error when publishing an application, we recommend using the Windows built-in `Resource Monitor` to check the specific situation of the occupied files.

**Any files are locked issue can be investigated through this tool.**

[image]